# making items blur in recylerview fitted in listview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, android-cardview

[image]

This is my app...in this i want that when i click on any of the cardview the background should blur and another should appear on selected one over the blur appearance and when the user clicks any one of buttons the user gets to new activity. i am using this [library](http://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover)

Help me to get Started. Thank you

Comment: You can use 'elevation'. Just give it a try. Or use a simple object animator to pull up the elements from the background

Comment: make your question more clear.

Answer (score 3):

As I can understand from your question you have recyclerViews inside listView and on recycler view item click you want to achieve like [this library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover) change your row item layout to something like this remember to  was wrap it by BlurLayout like following

```
<com.daimajia.androidviewhover.BlurLayout
        android:id="@+id/blurBg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        //copy here your recycler view row layout 
</com.daimajia.androidviewhover.BlurLayout>
```

create a layout which will appear on blurred background lets say overlay
like below

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   //you can place your buttons here or any layout which you want
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ok" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

now in your view holder of recycler view bind this view

```
public class yourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    BlurLayout blurLayout;
    View hover;
    public yourViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
      blurLayout = (BlurLayout)findViewById(R.id.blurBg);
      hover = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
      blurLayout.setHoverView(hover);
    }
    hover.findViewById(R.id.btnOk).setOnClickListener(new    View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do what you want
    });

}
```

let me know if I understood something wrong or you need something else

Answer (score 1):

If you want that view to appear on Individual items then you should use [Popup view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). Using that you can adjust its position based on anchor view and can customize it as required. Here's something that can help:

Use this inside onBindViewHolder().

```
holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();

        }
    });
```

You can specify its position based on recycler view items.

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39888321/2100079

Comment: Thank you for your answer...but i wanna make it that happen on the items and at that moment i want to blur that item

Answer (score 1):

You can use alpha property at runtime to blur image

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

                holder.thumbnail.setAlpha(0.5f);
                holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        holder.thumbnail.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AlertDailog with custom layout to achieve the same.

Usage and guidance can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)

Comment: i don't want dialog like that it will appear in the middle of screen..i want that on the respective cardview