# Cannot Go To New Activity When Row Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, java, android, listview, onclick

I have been trying to get a option menu to appear when a TextView is clicked.  I have been able to accomplish this.  However now when I click on the row I cannot go to the next activity.

[image]

This is my code in the MainActivity

```
//On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
                TextView buttonViewOption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
                TextView rowItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowItem);
                buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //creating a popup menu
                        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, buttonViewOption);
                        //inflating menu from xml resource
                        popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
                        //adding click listener
                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    case R.id.menu1:
                                        //handle menu1 click
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.menu2:
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.menu3:
                                        showLeagueDialog(true, leaguesList.get(position), position);
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.menu4:
                                        deleteLeague(position);
                                        break;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        //displaying the popup
                        popup.show();

                    }
                });
            }
               /*int leagueId = leaguesList.get(position).getId();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BowlerActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);*/
        @Override
        public void onRowClick(View view, int position) {
                    int leagueId = leaguesList.get(position).getId();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BowlerActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                }



            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }
```

RecyclerTouchListener.java

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private ClickListener clicklistener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final ClickListener clicklistener) {

        this.clicklistener = clicklistener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clicklistener != null) {
                    clicklistener.onLongClick(child, recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clicklistener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clicklistener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);
        void onRowClick(View view, int position);
        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

I have search through many different articles on this site and I have tried several different solutions that members have posted, but I am still unable to to a new activity.

How do you create a onClickListener() that will listen for both a click on the main row, as well as a TextView.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

BolwerAdapter.java

```
public class BowlerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BowlerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Bowler> bowlersList;

    public void notifyDatasetChanged(List<Bowler> newbowlerlist) {
        bowlersList.clear();
        bowlersList.addAll(newbowlerlist);
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView bowlerLeagueId;
        private TextView name;
        private TextView bowlerAverage;
        private TextView bowlerHandicap;
        private TextView timestamp;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            bowlerLeagueId = view.findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerName);
            bowlerAverage = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerAverage);
            bowlerHandicap = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerHandicap);
            timestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        }
    }

    BowlerAdapter(Context context, List<Bowler> bowlersList) {
        this.bowlersList = bowlersList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from( Objects.requireNonNull( parent ).getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listview_bowler, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bowler bowler = bowlersList.get(position);

        holder.bowlerLeagueId.setText(bowler.getLeagueId());
        holder.name.setText(bowler.getName());
        if (bowler.getAverage() != "") {
            holder.bowlerAverage.setText(String.format("Bowler Avg: %s", bowler.getAverage()));
        } else {
            holder.bowlerAverage.setText(String.format("Bowler Avg: %s", "0"));
        }
        Integer handicap = Integer.parseInt(bowler.getHandicap());
        if (handicap < 0) {
            holder.bowlerHandicap.setText(String.format("Bowler Handicap: %s", "0"));
        }
        if (bowler.getHandicap() != "" ){
            holder.bowlerHandicap.setText(String.format("Bowler Handicap: %s", bowler.getHandicap()));
        } else {
            holder.bowlerHandicap.setText(String.format("Bowler Handicap: %s", "0"));
        }
        //Formatting And Displaying Timestamp
        holder.timestamp.setText(formatDate(bowler.getTimestamp()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bowlersList.size();
    }

    //Formatting TimeStamp to 'EEE MMM dd yyyy (HH:mm:ss)'
    //Input  : 2018-05-23 9:59:01
    //Output : Wed May 23 2018 (9:59:01)
    private String formatDate(String dateStr) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy (HH:mm:ss)");
            return fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) { }

        return "";
    }
}
```

I have been able to get this to work by setting the onClick() to activate on a TextView. This is not ideal since I seem to have to double tap the text to switch activities.

My code in the MainActivity

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRowClick(View view, int position) {
                TextView listviewClick = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSeriesName);
                listviewClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int leagueId = leaguesList.get(position).getId();
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BowlerActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
                TextView buttonViewOption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
                buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //creating a popup menu
                        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, buttonViewOption);
                        //inflating menu from xml resource
                        popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
                        //adding click listener
                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    case R.id.menu1:
                                        //handle menu1 click
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.menu2:
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.menu3:
                                        showLeagueDialog(true, leaguesList.get(position), position);
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.menu4:
                                        deleteLeague(position);
                                        break;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        //displaying the popup
                        popup.show(); 
                    }
                }); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }
```

My listview xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rowItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10">

    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSeriesName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/leagueValue"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            autofit:minTextSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLeagueAverage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvSeriesName"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:text="League Average: 300"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvSeriesName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Fri May 18 2018"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLeagueId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvSeriesName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timestamp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBaseScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBaseScorePercentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorText1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewOptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="&#8942;"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

However when I use RelativeLayout listviewClick = view.findViewById(R.id.rowItem); I am only able to click on the row , not the options menu.

Comment: Well, I'll tell you how I do it in my apps. I do not create a touch listeners on the recyclerview items. Instead I give onClickListeners in holders to which ever View I want to give it to. then using their listeners, I do y jobs, because they can also fetch you positions. I made 5 apps similar to this strategy and none of them have onTouchListeners.

Comment: I tried doing this inside my LeagueAdapter and could not accomplish this either, this is the link to my other ticket using the adapter, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213241/create-options-menu-for-recyclerview-item) is this what you are referring too.

Comment: Where's your recycler view's adapter class? Can you post the code

Comment: @MohitGaur it is posted above, it is the RecyclerTouchListener.java.

Comment: You want to navigate to other activity when you click the row right?

Comment: Yes exactly,  I just can't seem to figure out how to get the listener to listen to both the button and the row.  My code for going to the new activity is currently commented out.

Comment: @UmangBurman Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: Sure, I would love to. Are you online now?

Comment: @UmangBurman Yes I am online now, I have post some new code above

Comment: Okay, let me have a look at it, I was waiting for you forever.. lol

Comment: @UmangBurman sorry I didn't realize I need to put you name in the comment in order for you to be notified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179844/discussion-between-umang-burman-and-robert-vogl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Remove the `recyclerview.onTouchListener...` .. We don't need this anymore.

click listeners on the `holder` objects works better than that. Please see the following example below:

Similar to `holder.bowlerLeagueId.setText(bowler.getLeagueId());` you can also write:

```
holder.bowlerLeagueId.setOnClickListener(....) {
     ........ (Write here)
}
```

Then, inside your (Write here) thing, write your code to navigate to next activity.

Similarly you can do it for any holder.viewid.setOnClick etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested this and it works like a charm, thank you so much for taking the time to walk me through this in a chat session.  Definitely learned something today.

Comment: Ain't no thing but a chicken wing, Mamacita.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to create a custom adapter class**

> **BowlerAdapter.java**

```
public class BowlerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BowlerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    List<Bowler> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public BowlerAdapter(Context context, List<BowlerAdapter> data) {
       inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;

    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recycler_view_single, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        BowlerAdapter current=data.get(position);
        holder.header.setText(current.header);
        holder.image.setImageResource(current.image);
        //.....
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        CTextView header;
        ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            header= (CTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aap_tv_header);
            image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aap_img_dog_s);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            BowlerAdapter current=data.get(pos);
            //Now here you can either use switch case or if statement to perform action on the basis of position
        }
    }
}
```

> In MainActivity.java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
recyclerView=(RecyclerView) fragView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
adapter=new BowlerAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
}


public List<Bowler> getData(){
//Here you will return your ArrayList<Bowler>
}
```

> In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/f1LinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rv">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is just a sample code. So, you can implement the logic in here. There can be other ways also.

Comment: Like what I just posted above

Comment: Yes, but the difference is that I have implemented onClick listener for every item clicked and you have implemented onClick or onTouch  on recyclerview. Please note!!

Comment: Please note, there is a difference between an item of recycler view and recycler view itself. If you know what I mean @RobertVogl

Comment: Where in MainActivity would you place this your last lines of code.  Don't you need a onClick to execute the code you posted for MainActivity

Comment: @RobertVogl Why would I need an onClick listener. It is just a reference variable. Like you get a reference to objects via findViewById(). You need to implement that code in onCreate.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your solution,  I am fairly new to android programming, I am basically teaching myself.

Comment: @RobertVogl I have updated my answer. I have posted all my code. That's all I can do from here. Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

May I know that have you register your BowlerActivity in the manifest file? please attach the log as well after you click the view.

I see you initialize the local listener and implement onLongClick & onTouch, but the view you didn't set OnClick event and transfer to customized Listener callback as OnRowClick

Comment: this should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: @AnubhavGupta He does not have enough reps to post it as a comment. Please see before downvoting. Thank to him that at least he is trying to help.

Comment: The BowlerActivity is registered in the manifest file, and there are no errors in logcat.  The row is simply not click-able.

Comment: @AnubhavGupta I saw a -1 earlier so I thought it was you as you commented. Sorry, if you havn't.

Comment: @RobertVogl I can't find the place you called onRowClick in the RecyclerTouchListener class

Comment: @RobertVogl  Yes, that is the callback method, but you need to call listener.onRowClick in #RecyclerTouchListener  class, in order to callback to the first snippet code

Comment: @YouhaiLU it is in the public interface ClickListener at the bottom of the RecyclerTouchListener class

Comment: @YouhaiLU  wouldn't this be my listener onRowClick() -  `public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);
        void onRowClick(View view, int position);
        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }`

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clicklistener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clicklistener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }

        return false;
    }

Comment: How would I set OnClick event and transfer to customized Listener callback as OnRowClick?

Comment: If I add `if (child != null && clicklistener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clicklistener.onRowClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        }`  I am simply reversing the results, I can now click on the row but not the options menu.  Not sure how to transfer the click to onRowClick()

Comment: I don't know why do you implement this onTouchListener in the first place, normally what we do, we create an adapter and view holder, and implement each view click event separately. Can u implement a new Adapter and implement this onRowClick event on Parent view click event and onClick event for subview click.

Comment: I tried doing this inside of my LeagueAdapter earlier but was not able to get this to work either. See here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213241/create-options-menu-for-recyclerview-item).  Is there away to get this to work the way I currently have it?

Comment: @RobertVogl the link above is caused by you initialized the wrong context which caused NullPointException