# PopUp menu in RecyclerView work in different item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having RecyclerView and beside informations every item has a button with three dots that represent a popup menu.When user click on that button a popup menu it show more info.Parts of item become visible.I can not use expendable RecyclerView i must use this. But the problem is when i click on it is expands and collapse only last item on my RecyclerView not that was clicked on.
I tried this:[Create Options Menu for RecyclerView-Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601346/create-options-menu-for-recyclerview-item) and couple other solutions bit my code is based on this SO question.

My code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AccountsHolder holder, int position) {
        AccountsModel model = list.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);
        holder.binding.moreInfoIB.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.assets_more_info_menu);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                Log.i("ItemID: ", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
                    if (isExpanded) {
                        collapse(group);
                        isExpanded = false;

                    } else {
                        isExpanded = true;
                        expand(group);

                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();
        });

    }
```

edit my entire Adapter class: `

```
public class CashAccAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CashAccAdapter.AccountsHolder> {
    private List<AccountsModel> list;
    private Context context;
    private boolean isExpanded;
    private Group group;
    //SparseBooleanArrays map integers to booleans.
    private SparseBooleanArray expandedList = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public CashAccAdapter(List<AccountsModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AccountsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ItemDetailedListAssetsBinding binding = ItemDetailedListAssetsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        group = binding.group;
        return new AccountsHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AccountsHolder holder, int position) {
        AccountsModel model = list.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);
        holder.binding.moreInfoIB.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.assets_more_info_menu);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                Log.i("ItemID: ", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
                    if (expandedList[position]) {
                        collapse(group);
                        expandedList[position] = false;

                    } else {
                        expandedList [position]= true;
                        expand(group);

                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list != null ? list.size() : 0;
    }

    class AccountsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ItemDetailedListAssetsBinding binding;

        public AccountsHolder(@NonNull ItemDetailedListAssetsBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public void bind(final AccountsModel modelClass) {
            binding.setListAssets(modelClass);
            binding.executePendingBindings();

            binding.accNameValueTV.setText(modelClass.getAccName());
            binding.accTypeValueTV.setText(modelClass.getAccType());
            binding.accCurentValueTV.setText("$" + modelClass.getCurrentValue());
            binding.accNumberValueTV.setText(modelClass.getAccNumber());
        }

    }
}
```

`

Comment: What is "group" you are passing in collapse and expand methods? Second Right way of doing it to keep isExpanded flag in your AccountsModel and setExpanded on click your pop of your model and call notifyDataSetChange.

Comment: It is my viewes grouped in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

declare a SparseBooleanArray named `expandedList` and change this part to

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                Log.i("ItemID: ", String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
                    if (expanded.get(position)) {
                        collapse(group);
                        expandedList.put(position, false);
                    } else {
                        expandedList.put(position, true);
                        expand(group);
                    }
                    this.notifyItemChanged(position);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
```

Only last item changes because you are using a single `isExpanded` variable. So, try the above code. Good Luck. :)

Comment: i tried but got an error when i tried  if (expandedList[position]) line of code

Comment: have you declared expandedList? can you provide the full file?

Comment: Yes i did private SparseBooleanArray expandedList = new SparseBooleanArray();

Comment: I added my adapter class

Comment: i think you are getting error because you initially set the list capacity to 1. ```    private SparseBooleanArray expandedList = new SparseBooleanArray(1);
```

Comment: i delete it and it is the same i got error error: array required, but SparseBooleanArray found
                    if (expandedList[position])

Comment: sorry sorry. I mistyped with kotlin. try this. ```expandedList.get(position)```

Comment: i updated my answer. please check it and update in yours. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Do this fro according to your need..

```
 holder.et_name_input.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {

 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);

if (CountryCode.equals("BR")) {

popup.getMenu().add("SAVING");

popup.getMenu().add("CHECKING");

} else if (CountryCode.equals("IN")) {

 popup.getMenu().add("Current account");

 popup.getMenu().add("Savings account");

 popup.getMenu().add("Salary account");

 }
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {

holder.et_name_input.setText(item.getTitle());

return false;

});

popup.show();

});
```